# Cannot access widget.user from my custom widget named _appBar in Flutter? the error shows Undefined name 'widget'

Tags: flutter

I am initializing the ChatUser user object while navigating to this screen. But am unable to access user.name from inside my custom made widget.

```
Text(
              //show user.name
              widget.user.name,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
```

Here is the full code:

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:we_chat/constants.dart';
import 'package:we_chat/models/user.dart';

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final ChatUser user;
  ChatScreen({required this.user});
  @override
  State<ChatScreen> createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          flexibleSpace: _appBar(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _appBar() {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Row(
      children: [
        //back button
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_rounded,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        //profile picture
        CachedNetworkImage(
          // imageUrl: widget.User.imageUrl,
          imageUrl:
              'https://media.istockphoto.com/id/846147812/photo/rainbow-lorikeet.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=rWz0KREDv2ihrPkwate0cLGR41zNs8jnpQ6lrWkQpqs=',
          imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
            width: mq.width * 0.1,
            height: mq.height * 0.1,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: imageProvider,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          placeholder: (context, url) => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),
        ),

        //space
        const SizedBox(
          width: 10.0,
        ),

        //name and status
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              //show user.name
              widget.user.name,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'Online',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12.0,
                color: Colors.white70,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

I am unable show the name from the ChatUser user object. How can i do that?

Comment: @AhmadF I don't have access to the code at the moment. As soon I get access to that I will provide that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access `widget` property inside `_appBar()` because is a separate method that returns `Widget`, which has nothing to do with the `_ChatScreenState` class.

To fix this, you could pass the user object to the `_appBar()`:

```
Widget _appBar({required ChatUser user}) {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Row(
      children: [
        //back button
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_rounded,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),

        //space
        const SizedBox(
          width: 10.0,
        ),

        //name and status
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              // user.name without "widget"
              user.name,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'Online',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12.0,
                color: Colors.white70,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Hence:

```
class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          flexibleSpace: _appBar(user: widget.user),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Or you can declare the `_appBar()` method inside the `_ChatScreenState` class:

```
class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          flexibleSpace: _appBar(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _appBar() {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Row(
        children: [
          //back button
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back_rounded,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),

          //space
          const SizedBox(
            width: 10.0,
          ),

          //name and status
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                // now you can access the user.name from the widget
                widget.user.name,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'Online',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.0,
                  color: Colors.white70,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks a lot. If it is inside the _ChatScreenState class only then I get to use widget.user. Otherwise I must pass the object.